# Lightning Component force:hasSObjectName, sObjectName undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, interface

Per the force:hasSObjectName interface [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasSObjectName/documentation), I can reference an automatically added attribute named sObjectName to retrieve the object where my custom lightning component is being accessed. However when I try to use this value, it is undefined (code below): 
Is this the correct way to reference the sObjectName? I'm aware I can pull this value from the record id, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component controller="lc_BuyerSellerSearchCriteriaCTRL" implements="force:hasSObjectName,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" description="lc_BuyerSellerSearchCriteriaDynamic" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <!--Component Code-->
</aura:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log(cmp.get('v.sObjectName'));
}
```

This statement in the console log shows *undefined*

Comment: Is your component placed on the record context, viz., record layout?

Comment: It's embedded within a custom tab on the record layout

Comment: That should still work fine. You should verify if there's something else going in your `init` function which is blocking the component to be rendered completely. I can confirm that it works if added to a custom tab.

Comment: adding to utilityBar works, however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a quick test I can confirm that this works fine as long as your component is within the right context. The same is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasSObjectName/documentation) (emphasis mine).

> Important The `sObjectName` **attribute is set only when you place or invoke the component in an explicit record context**. For example, when you place the component directly on a record page layout, or invoke it as an object-specific action from a record page or object home. In all other cases, such as when you invoke the component as a global action, or create the component programmatically inside another component, `sObjectName` isn’t set, and your component shouldn’t depend on it.
>
> These unsupported contexts include a few contexts that might seem like they should have access to the current record. Examples of these other contexts include the following:
>
> - Invoking the component from a global action (even when you’re on a record page)
> - Invoking the component from header or footer navigation in a community (even if the page shows a record)
>
> `force:hasRecordId` and `force:hasSObjectName` are unsupported in these contexts. While the marker interfaces still add the relevant attribute to the component, accessing either attribute generally returns `null` or `undefined`.

You will need to verify that the component you have is placed within the correct record context.

Comment: Is a custom tab on the record's layout (ie next to the record's standard "Details" tab) not explicit enough context?

Comment: It is. And I can confirm that it works in that context too. As soon as you click on the Tab, your component gets initialized and you will get the `sObjectName`.

Comment: The force:hasSObject interface works when the component is directly on the record layout page but for the same component it doesn't work when it is on a custom tab on the same page. The component in question is a child component within a parent

Comment: It won't work that way. It has to be directly within the component on the record context based on the documentation -- *or create the component programmatically inside another component*